# Prove that there is $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = g(c)$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous such that $f(a) < g(a)$ and $f(b) > g(b)$. Prove that there is $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = g(c).$

**Attempt**:

Let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. Then $h(a) < 0$ and $h(b) > 0$ while there exists a $c$ such that $h(c) = 0$. Then isn't it obvious that $h(x)$ must be zero at some point by the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Your attempt is absolutely correct.

Comment: "while there exists a $c$" is a bit unclear, should be omitted. Then one says that by the Intermediate Value Theorem there is a $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $\dots$.

Comment: You are right. Just mention that since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $h$ is continuous on the same interval. You can quote a theorem or lemma from your book to this effect.